# Where do I go to edit the CMS Home Page?

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

Using Magento 2, I uploaded a theme and trying to edit the imported demo home page. but I can't find where to edit that page to change the blocks on it.

When I go to `Content > Pages`, there's a "Home" listed there but that's for `example.com/home`, not just `example.com`.

[image: Content > Pages view]

Answer (score 7):

Magento 2 Edit CMS page to show

> go to **Admin >> Contents >> CMS**

By default CMS page

> **Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> General >> Web >> Default Pages >> As u select CMS** as a by default

Answer (score 2):

Login dashboard, in the

> Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page

you will find what is the page you need to edit.

If that page is not the right one. Maybe your theme use block to make homepage. Go to **Content > Block**, search "**home**" keyword in the title, you will get some block which should be the right one.